# Convert a whole wordpress blog to PDF

Tags: wordpress

Do you know if is possible to convert a whole wordpress blog to PDF?

I tried some WP plugins but they get an error in multisite platform.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could configure it so that it will show all articles and tehn you print into a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this new Wordpress plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blogtopdf/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.